# Play removing the trailing "==" from request

Tags: html, rest, jakarta-ee, playframework-2.0

The issue I am facing while making a call to my application (Written in playframework 2.3) one of the REST request having a hash string

url : /data is a update request where I am sending data with PUT verb and the item code is an hash string (eg "abcid==").

I am sending the request content type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded

and at server side I am getting the data with following code,

```
final Map<String, String[]> values = request().body()
                    .asFormUrlEncoded();
List<String> itemCodeList = Arrays.asList(values.get("itemCodeList"));
```

but the itemCodeList elements having the itemcode as "abcid".

I am not sure that the hash will always generate the string with trailing "==", So can't apend the "==" in the itemCodeList elements.

Answer (score 1):

The request should be url-encoded. so 'abcid==' should be send as 'abcid%3D%3D'.
You can use [Web Url Endcoder/Decoder](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) to encode text.

Comment: The client should do the encode.
If your client is written in Java you can use [Java URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html)

Comment: I am getting the request from the UI, but unable to encode it in playframework.

Comment: What do you mean "from the UI"? Is it Play template?  Is it from javascript ?  You can post the code of the controller and the client which call it, to have the whole context.

Comment: I am trying with the Chrome REST Client Advanced REST client 3.1.7 and the Controller code is same as the above post (in question).

Comment: You have like there to encode the payload (on the raw tab) - just put there "itemCodeList=abcid==" and click the 'Encode payload', or you can just encode it manually with sites like I linked in the answer.
ju

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62256/discussion-between-roterl-and-rakesh-chouhan).